# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling cvThreshold

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when calling cvThreshold. Without that line (if I comment it), the image is displayed perfectly.

```
void CVWindow::processImage()
{
    sourceImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),8,1);
    cvSetData(sourceImg, &m_img, sourceImg->widthStep);

    cvThreshold(sourceImg, sourceImg, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    m_img = *sourceImg->imageData;
}
```

Any possible reasons? I have been searching for two days for a solution but cant find it.
Thanks